# Should I write an extension or a tampermonkey script?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, tampermonkey

I would like to implement some functions on browsers and I was wondering if tampermonkey script a good choice. Or should I just write an extension?

Considering cross-platform consistency, tampermonkey maybe better than browser extension.

Is there any concerns I should consider?

Or put it another way: When should I consider writing an extension and when should I consider writing a script?

I know this is not a good question, but I can't find any useful information on google. Some advice will be helpful.

Thank you!!

---

**UPDATE**

What I want to do is basically provide a UI for browsers' "inspect".

Take chrome for example.

1. right click at a web page
2. click inspect
3. select "Elements"
4. click on any tag and right click
5. there's a "copy" and you can copy "selector" or "xpath"

And I want to be able to click on the element directly on the page, and copy its "selector" or "xpath" to clipboard.

Both script or extension seem to work. I want to know which one is better for this purpose.

Comment: The question is too broad. We don't even know what you want to do in the code and that may be the most important factor if it's something not supported by Tampermonkey. A practical solution is to start with whatever solution you like then see if has problems, and if there is none then you're fine.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for your response. I've updated my question. I've experienced much trial&errors these days, and just want to make sure I'm on the right way.

Comment: Sounds like a task that requires the standard stuff (DOM, CSS, JS) and nothing specific to extensions. If you use Tampermonkey anyway then a simple userscript is fine. If your code grows and you want to add some extension-specific things then of course use an extension.

Answer (score 2):

There are more other viewpoints.

- How easy to install for users. If you release your stuff as a user script, it depends on Tampermonkey or other similar extensions, so people need to install two things. An extension is installable directly.
- Some people cannot use user scripts due to security reasons. Tampermonkey itself requires very wide permissions, so some people don't like install it, and sometimes such an addon can be banned on company environment. On the other hand, an extension will have only minimum permissions.

Of course a user script is easier to maintain for the author. An extension needs to do more tasks on every release.